# Web Accessibility Issue and validation of wordpress website

Tags: html, wordpress, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm running a site though Web Accessibility and getting the following report warning:

> Ensure ARIA regions, landmarks and HTML sections are identifiable.

The code it refers to is below as follows:

```html
<aside style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="widget widget_text masonry-brick" id="text-2">
   <h3 class="widget-title">My Website</h3>
   <div class="textwidget">
      <p>Address Line 1<br>Address Line 2<br>Telephone: 123-456-7890<br></p>
   </div>
</aside>
```

I'm not super familiar with web accessibility issues so I am not sure what change needs to be made. The code snippet is in the widget area, which then places that in the footer section of the website.

I need to know if I need to add an id or aria label. As it sits inside the footer there is already a 'footer' established and then this is an 'aside' created within that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way than using `aria-label` is to use [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) and give the `aside` title an ID.

```html
<!-- add `aria-labelledby` to the aside, pointing it to the ID of the heading. -->
<aside aria-labelledby="aside-title" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="widget widget_text masonry-brick" id="text-2">
   <!-- add a corresponding ID to the aside heading -->
   <h3 id="aside-title" class="widget-title">My Website</h3>
   <div class="textwidget">
      <p>Address Line 1<br>Address Line 2<br>Telephone: 123-456-7890<br></p>
   </div>
</aside>
```

This is due to some strange behaviour in some edge case screen readers where `aria-label` will overwrite the content of anything inside with the `aria-label` text. This is especially important with items that do not have focusable elements inside them.

Taken from [MDN on `aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute):

> The `aria-label` attribute is used to define a string that labels the current element. Use it in cases where a text label is **not** visible on the screen. If there is visible text labelling the element, use `aria-labelledby` instead.

Taken from [MDN on `aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute):

> In addition to form elements, you can use the `aria-labelledby` attribute to associate static text with widgets, groups of elements, panes, regions that have a heading, definitions, and other types of objects. The Examples section below provides more information on how to use the attribute this way.